# JPEG to transparent PNG causes black bleeding

Tags: opengl, image-processing, imagemagick, png, jpeg

I need to do the following : I have a standard JPEG image as input.What I need to do is to convert it to PNG 32bit(alpha transparency) and set a transparent border of some amount of pixels.

I tried to use ImageMagic these commands:

```sh
convert  xxx.jpg xxx.png 

convert xxx.png -channel RGBA -separate -resize 500x500 -combine xxx.png 

convert xxx.png -alpha set -channel RGBA -separate \
        -background "RGBA(0,0,0,0)" -gravity center \
        -extent 550x550 -composite xxx1.png
```

And that's the result after I am using this image in OpenGL  program which premultiplies it on the output as there is a need for alpha blending.

[image]

The black edge is where the part of original JPEG image ends(there is also 10 pixels transparent border around the visible edge) and it means that the image resulting from the ImageMagic is probably  premultiplied which is not what I want.I need it to be unremultiplied just like Photoshop exports PNG images in unpremultiplied state.This way I can get rid from the black border artifacts.

The bleeding happens if I use linear interpolation like GL_LINEAR or GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR.It is also stated in many sources that this bleeding is the result of linear interpolation of neighbor pixels.

Strangely.If I do such a setup in Photoshop,that's,dropping JPG into transparent canvas and then saving it to PNG24 with transparency channel then the bleeding is gone.Also,if I drop the resulting PNG from the above mentioned ImageMagic process and re-save it with Photoshop then it gets fixed as well.I can't use Photoshop as I need a command line tool like ImageMagic to create those images.I could also use something customized via C++ code,but I currently have no idea how to get rid of that black edge.

Comment: Maybe try all of other commands from http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/thumbnails/#pad ?

Comment: Already checked it.Doesn't work.ImageMagic exports JPGs differently from Photoshop.

Comment: You mean if you save xxx.png from photoshop and run commands 2 and 3, there is no bleeding?

Comment: No,I mean if I take the picture which has already been passed thru ImageMagic with 1,2,3 commands and re-save it to PNG then it gets fixed.

Comment: Could you post links to image generated using Photoshop (a good result) and an image generated using ImageMagick (one that causes bleeding). From the description I'm not sure how is it supposed to look like, but If you post the images, I'll look into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use [this C++ command-line tool](http://www.stud.fit.vutbr.cz/~xpolok00/proj/AddTransparentBorder.zip). There is a precompiled windows binary and an example of a modified image. It does not do anything with the image, it just sets zero alpha border around it (no premultiplication). To build this you need libjpeg and libpng (you can get x86 / x64 prebuilt windws libs [here](http://www.stud.fit.vutbr.cz/~xpolok00/proj/libjpeg_libpng.zip)).

A couple of notes about OpenGL. The bleeding of the edges can be only up to 1 pixel wide and is caused by repetitive texture application. You can remove it even if using `GL_LINEAR` or `GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR` mode by setting clamp mode to `GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE`:

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
```

In case you are not using `GL_TEXTURE_2D`, you need to replace that with whatever you are using. The bleeding is kind of suspicious, and may be also related to the RGB color that is in the regions that have zero alpha. The correct way to set up the blending mode is:

```
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

This way anything that is with zero alpha does not have any influence on the pixels under it. However, the interpolation may cause bleeding of the black pixels with zero alpha to the first pixel of the image with 100% alpha, yielding a thin black border. To get rid of that, it is necessary to replicate the color of the edge of the original image to the border and set zero alpha.

To do that, define `__BLEED_EDGE` when compiling, or use the precompiled `AddTransparentBorder_BleedEdge` version. There is also an example of an image with the edges duplicated. You can try to use those examples first and see if the black edge occurs.

Comment: Nope.CLAMP won't solve it.I am using this mode.What does slove is GL_NEAREST interpolation.Because LINEAR samples nearest pixels and on edges some of those are black with zero alpha.That's where the bleeding comes from.But I can't stay with NEAREST as I use  smooth mipmapping

Comment: Well, I should probably give more emphasis in the answer. There are two cases where bleeding occurs. One at the edges of the texture (and that is fixed by the clamp), and the other near pixels with zero alpha. The bleed edge mode of the tool solves this latter issue.

Comment: @MichaelIV How did it work out? Did you get to try it?

Comment: @MichaelIV well I sometimes forget there are such things (you seem too as you are sitting by your computer). Enjoy your weekend.

Answer (score 0):

For me, this produces an out.png that contains only 0 and 100% alphas, using
the current ImageMagick (which is version 6.8.9-0):

```
convert in.jpg -alpha set -bordercolor none -border 25x25 png32:out.png
```

Comment: Exactly ,that is the problem.When those (o,o,o,o) pixels are interpolated with visible pixels they add to the final color black .

Comment: If you are rescaling the PNG afterwards, that can't be helped.  It is the final zero (alpha value) that is getting interpolated with the alpha value (1) from the neighboring pixel, and that is happening in OPENGL.  To "fix" the PNG with ImageMagick, you'd need to know the color you are planning to composite it against and use that color, but transparent (e.g., #ffff0000 for transparent yellow).